# Resources for learning about filters from scratch?

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response, digital-filters, reference-request

Topic of filters is very important in signal processing

So i want to learn about filters from scratch and then eventually reaching FIR and IIR filters

I have some idea about low pass,high pass,band pass,band stop types but often get confused how they relate to butterworth, chebyshev and other such types?

Apart from wikipedia, please recommend books chapters or websites for learning about filters

Answer (score 3):

The best book I know that exclusively treats digital filters is [Digital Filter Design by Parks and Burrus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471828963).

But any good textbook on signal processing has one or more chapters about properties and design of digital filters. And since the most common IIR filter designs are based on analog filters, these books usually also treat the classic analog filter approximations like Butterworth, Chebyshev, Cauer (elliptic), and Bessel.

Two good undergraduate texts are [Digital Signal Processing by Proakis and Manolakis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8131710009) and [Digital Signal Processing Using Matlab by Ingle and Proakis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9386668114).

Also take a look at the answers to [this very related question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/14016/4298).

Comment: Learning resource recommendations are on-topic in this SE?

Answer (score 2):

Online, I learned a lot from the sections of [Introduction to digital filters with audio applications](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/filters/) by Julius O. Smith III.

In addition to the series of books by Matt L., I suggest another from Manolakis, and two from Maurice Bellanger (one of the references is in French, there might be a translation), who cared for precision in filter coefficients

- [Statistical and adaptive signal processing. Spectral estimation, signal modeling, adaptive filtering and array processing](https://lr.ttu.ee/%7Eameister/materjale/Dig_spe_anal/Statistical%20and%20Adaptive%20Signal%20Processing.pdf), Manolakis, D. G.; Ingle, V. K. & Kogon, S. M.
- [Traitement numérique du signal. Théorie et pratique, Maurice Bellanger](https://www.dunod.com/sciences-techniques/traitement-numerique-du-signal), Dunod, 2006
- [Adaptive digital filters](http://twanclik.free.fr/electricity/electronic/PDFDONE1/Adaptive%20Digital%20Filters%20Second%20Edition.pdf), Bellanger, M. G.

Comment: +1, especially for the reference to the JOS page.